# Interference between two graphs using 'paths'

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm building a dashboard with a couple of d3 visualizations, which looks like:

[image: example]

The way I built this is by making a few div's on the page, and call the .js script inside these divs. This worked perfectly fine so far. Unfortunately I run into a problem when calling my .js file with a line graph on the right top div on my page. When I call the graph.js file, this happens:

[image: problemo]

I'm not entirely sure what's happening, but I think both the visualizations are using "path" elements, and therefore they interfere with eachother. This is the main code for the map of Europe:

```
//Load in GeoJSON data
        d3.json("ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json", function(json) {
            //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
            svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.continent == 'Europe'}) //we only want Europe to be shown ánd loaded.
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "border")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("fill", "#ADD8E6")
                .attr("countryName", function(d){return d.properties.sovereignt})
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {  
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(200)      
                        .style("opacity", .9);      
                    div .html(d.properties.sovereignt + ', ' + getCountryTempByYear(dataset, d.properties.sovereignt, document.getElementById("selectYear").value)) 
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                })                  
                .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                    div.transition()        
                        .duration(500)      
                        .style("opacity", 0);
                })  
                .on("click", function(d){
                    //add/delete country to/from selected countries
                    updateSelectedCountries(d.properties.sovereignt);

                    //draw the temperature visualizations again
                    redrawTemp(getCountryTempByYear(dataset, selectedCountries[0], document.getElementById("selectYear").value), getCountryTempByYear(dataset, selectedCountries[1], document.getElementById("selectYear").value));

                    //update header from the webpage
                    d3.select("#header").text("Climate Change: 1840-2013. Currently viewing: " + selectedCountries + ", " + document.getElementById("selectYear").value + '.');
                    console.log(selectedCountries);
                });
        });
```

And this is the code for the line graph:

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the grap
var array = [[1850, 11.1], [1851, 11.7], [1852, 12.2], [1853, 11.1], [1854, 11.7], [1855, 12.2], [1856, 13.4]]
var array2 = [[1850, 14.1], [1851, 17.7], [1852, 22.2], [1853, 13.1], [1854, 24.7], [1855, 19.2], [1856, 13.4]]


// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 200]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([200, 0]);

    // define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(array[i][0]); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(array[i][1]); })
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); //smooth line

var valueline2 = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return x(array2[i][0]); })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(array2[i][1]); })
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX); //smooth line

var svg = d3.select("#div2")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("id", "graph");

x.domain([1850, 1856]);
y.domain([10, 25]);

array.forEach(function(data, i){
    svg.append("path")
      .data([array])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);
})   

array2.forEach(function(data, i){
    svg.append("path")
        .data([array2])
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline2);
})

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 200 + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

As I said, I'm not entirely sure it's because of the graphs both using the "path" element, it could be something different too. Now what I'm wondering is: what is interfering with eachother? And how can I prevent this?

I can imagine something like a filter needs to be applied, but I'm not sure how to apply this to the right "path" elements.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hello Sandertjuhh, since js codes run sequentially, I would assume that it is happening because you are using the same variable for both graphs "var svg". Try to change it and let me know if it works, so I can create an official answer.

Comment: Hey Roger. You were absolutely right, I changed a few variables and now it looks fine. However, something else doesn't work right now, for some reason when I change the range slider it gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sovereignt' of undefined
    at SVGPathElement.<anonymous> ((index):261)

Comment: Which is pretty weird, because that worked before and nothing has changed.

Comment: Is this one of the new variables? if so, check if you are instantiating right 'var sovereignt = ...'

Comment: It's not. Basically what I do for the main graph is I loop over a json file. In this loop I have access to d.properties.sovereignt. This works on other places and has worked the whole time, but maybe I'm reusing variables somewhere else too.

Comment: Probably not, because it is saying that this variable is undefined, so you are probably not declaring it or losing the scope of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new chart you should create a new variable to associate with it.

In your case, this might be happening due to the reuse of the variable `var svg =...`.

Create one variable for each chart should be enough.